# Solution of the equation below

Tags: trigonometry

The solution of the equation $\sin 7x + \cos 2x = -2$ is/are?

My Approach: For the above equation to hold true, Both $\sin 7x$ and $\cos 2x$ have to be -1.

$$\sin 7x = -1$$
$$x = \frac{n\pi}{7} + (-1)^n(-\frac{\pi}{14})$$

Also,

$$\cos 2x = -1$$
$$x = n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$$

But the answer is $2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Your initial remark is fine, and your answer is (partially) correct. The  *condensed* answer is $n\pi+\dfrac\pi 2$ since $-\dfrac\pi2=\dfrac\pi2-\pi$. Similarly the first answer can be written in a more simple way as $\dfrac{n\pi}7-\dfrac\pi{14}$.

Comment: So how do I get the actual answer given?

Comment: The answer given is for the initial equation, I supppose?

Answer (score 1):

It should be $$7x=-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k$$ and $$2x=\pi+2\pi m,$$ where $\{k,m\}\subset\mathbb Z$, which gives
$$2\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k\right)=7(\pi+2\pi m)$$ or
$$2k-7m=4$$ or
$$2k-6m-4=m.$$

Thus, $m=2n$ and from here
$$2x=\pi+4\pi n$$ or
$$x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n,$$ where $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

use that $$\sin(x)+\cos(y)=2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$7x=2n\pi-\dfrac\pi2=(4n-1)\dfrac\pi2$$

and

$$2x=(2m+1)\pi$$ where $m,n$ are integers

On division,  $$7(2m+1)=4n-1$$

$\iff2(n-2)/7=m$ which is an integer

$\implies7\mid(n-2)$ as $(4,7)=1$

WLOG, $n-2=7r$ where $r$ is any integer

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Didn't understand your solution at all. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @PianoLand, We need both values to be satisfied for integers $m,n$ right?

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote it, this equation is equivalent to the system of equations
$$\sin 7x =-1,\qquad \cos2x=-1.$$
Now

- $\sin 7x=-1 \iff 7x\equiv -\dfrac\pi2\mod 2\pi\iff x\equiv -\dfrac\pi{14}\mod \dfrac{2\pi}7 $,
- $\cos 2x=-1\iff 2x\equiv\pi\mod 2\pi\iff x\equiv\dfrac\pi2\mod\pi$.

This  means we must have integers $k,\ell$ such that
$$x=-\frac\pi{14}+ \frac{2k\pi}7= \frac{(4k-1)\pi}{14}=\frac\pi2+\ell\pi=\frac{(14\ell+7)\pi}{14}.\tag{1}$$
So we have to solve for $4k-1=14\ell+7$ in integers, i.e. $\;2k-7\ell=4$ $(k,\ell \in\mathbf Z)$.

Start from the *Bézout's relation* $\;2\cdot 4-7=1$. We deduce $\;2\cdot 16-7\cdot 4=4$, so a basic solution is $\;(k,\ell)=(16,4)$, hence the general solution for $k$ and $\ell$:
$$k=16+7u,\quad\ell=4+2u\qquad(u \in\mathbf Z)$$
and finally, replacing in $(1)$: 
$$x=\frac\pi2+\ell\pi=\frac\pi2+(2+u)2\pi,$$
which may be rewritten as $\;\dfrac\pi2+2n\pi$.

Comment: Didn't understand how did get $k = 16 + 7u$ and $l = 4+2u$ and then suddenly this $x=\frac{\pi}{2} + l\pi$. Can you please explain?

Comment: For the values of $k$ and $\ell$, this is a standard result from linear diophantine equations $ax+by=c$  when $a$ and $b$ are coprime: if $(x_0,y_0)$ is a solution, all other solutions  can be written as $x=x_0+bt,\;y=y_0-at$. As to $x=\frac\pi2+\ell\pi$, this comes the equation (which I've just numbered $(1)$ to make it clearer).